# Console Application creates empty zip files

Tags: c#, zip

Somehow my console application creates empty (0 byte) Zip files while running. But if I set a breakpoint, and use F10 to traverse the packing function, zip is created normally.

This behaviour is the same on two computers, I've already tried zipping with DotNetZip and SharpZipLib to no effect.

The zipping function (using System.IO.Packaging) is the following:

```
private static void CreateModVersionZip(string path, string zipname)
{
    using (Package zip = System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(zipname, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        string destFilename = ".\\mods\\" + Path.GetFileName(path);
        Uri uri = PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(new Uri(destFilename, UriKind.Relative));
        if (zip.PartExists(uri))
        {
            zip.DeletePart(uri);
        }
        PackagePart part = zip.CreatePart(uri, "", CompressionOption.Normal);
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (Stream dest = part.GetStream())
            {
                CopyStream(fileStream, dest);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to make it work properly?

I can provide zipping snippets for SharpZipLib and DotNetZip if you need them.

Comment: Are you trying to zip a file or directory?

Comment: what does `CopyStream` do exactly? Are the streams flushed?

Comment: @ConnorWright I'm trying to zip a .jar file

Comment: @ArgusMagnus CopyStream just copies all bytes from one stream to another, and as you can see, there is `using` constraint, so the `Stream` should be closed normally.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no problem in my code, I found my problem in another place, where I send the file to the FTP. I used the snippet from CodeProject, and it looks like the author had a small mistake in opening the file (the method recreated the file instead of opening).